# Manual crop stopped working for drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I'm running Drupal 7.41 with the Manual Crop module 7.x-1.5

I've got one site where it works and another site where it doesn't work. I've recreated the crop as a Feature in the second site so all the Image Styles and settings should be the same.

When I go to add an image, the overlay comes up and it appears to crop the image. It even saves the image preview in the correct aspect ratio. But when I go to save it, it displays a broken link on the page and in the slideshow where the image is displayed in another page, it does not crop the image, but shows it in its original aspect ratio.

I checked the image directories and it's not saving the cropped version. In the logs I got this error:

**File not found:
http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/preview_image/public/main-slideshow/image.jpg?itok=Yc6VGave**

Why is this working on one site and not the other and how can I get it to work the same on the other sites?